# Remove outer Array of Objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I’ve got an JavaScript Array of Objects. These Objects have a unique identifier as a String. Since there is no need to have them in an array, how do I get rid of the outer array?

When trying to pop, (un)shift, etc. I’m always losing either UniqueStringA or UniqueStringB

I added a jsbin link here: https://jsbin.com/sulozeyelo/edit?js,console

**What I got**

```
const arrObj = [
    {
        "UniqueStringA": {
        "abc": [
            {
            "PropPair": {
                "a": "c",
                "b": "d"
            }
            },
            {
            "PropPair": {
                "a": "c",
                "b": "d"
            }
            }
        ],
        "def": [],
        "efg": [
            {
            "PropPair": {
                "a": "c",
                "b": "d"
            }
            },
            {
            "PropPair": {
                "a": "c",
                "b": "d"
            }
            }
        ],
        "xyz": []
        }
    },
    {
        "UniqueStringB": {
        "abc": [
            {
            "PropPair": {
                "a": "c",
                "b": "d"
            }
            },
            {
            "PropPair": {
                "a": "c",
                "b": "d"
            }
            }
        ],
        "def": [],
        "efg": [
            {
            "PropPair": {
                "a": "c",
                "b": "d"
            }
            },
            {
            "PropPair": {
                "a": "c",
                "b": "d"
            }
            }
        ],
        "xyz": []
        }
    }
];
```

**Result** should be like:

```
const obj =     {
    "UniqueStringA": {
        "abc": [
        {
            "PropPair": {
            "a": "c",
            "b": "d"
            }
        },
        {
            "PropPair": {
            "a": "c",
            "b": "d"
            }
        }
        ],
        "def": [],
        "efg": [
        {
            "PropPair": {
            "a": "c",
            "b": "d"
            }
        },
        {
            "PropPair": {
            "a": "c",
            "b": "d"
            }
        }
        ],
        "xyz": []
    },
    "UniqueStringB": {
        "abc": [
        {
            "PropPair": {
            "a": "c",
            "b": "d"
            }
        },
        {
            "PropPair": {
            "a": "c",
            "b": "d"
            }
        }
        ],
        "def": [],
        "efg": [
        {
            "PropPair": {
            "a": "c",
            "b": "d"
            }
        },
        {
            "PropPair": {
            "a": "c",
            "b": "d"
            }
        }
        ],
        "xyz": []
    }
};
```

Comment: `let obj = arr[0]` ... ???

Comment: You can access through index or pop out the object using `array#pop`.

Comment: I've upvoted just for how this question is clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```js
const arrObj = [
  {
    "uniqueStringA": {
      "abc": [{
        "propPair": {
          "A": "Hello",
          "B": "World"
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    "uniqueStringB": {
      "abc": [{
        "propPair": {
          "A": "Hello",
          "B": "World"
        }
      }]
    }
  }];

const obj = Object.assign({}, ...arrObj );

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I updated my code. I’m losing uniqueStringA when doing you method